# Debugging issue with workflow service application

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

For some reason none of the breakpoints I set on activities (through the designer) are working in a workflow service application project I'm debugging in VS2010.  There's an mvc application that uses the workflow services and I've tried setting them both as startup projects and setting only the workflow service application as the startup and calling it via the WCF test client.

Is there any setting I could have wrong that would prevent breakpoints from working?  I know the activities that have the breakpoints set are being processed (based on results) they just never break execution when the breakpoint is hit.

Additional info

- all projects are set to build with debug config
- workflow service is xamlx workflow being hosted with ASP.NET development server (VS F5)

Comment: please provide more information... does this happen when all participating apps/services have been built as Debug ? Is the workflow service self-hosted / IIS-hosted / Windows Service ?

Comment: @Yahia - I added the info you requested.  Let me know if there's anything else that would be helpful.

Comment: thanks - I added another link which you should check out... there are several situations where debugging WF is not fully possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important is that the project containing the workflow where the breakpoint is set is the startup project. Another thing that will often help is creating a CodeActivity with just Debugger.Break() in it and adding that to your workflow.

Comment: The workflow service project is set as a startup project.  I have don't have any problems setting a breakpoint inside a CodeActivity that I've created.  I just can't seem to get breakpoints to work in the designer.  I'd really like to be able to step through a flowchart but just can't seem to make it work.

Comment: I have the same issue. I can step through the breakpoint if I am on the xaml view but I can't step through on the designer.

Answer (score 2):

If workflow's xaml file has been moved, the breakpoints will stop working.

To solve: Open xaml file (as code, not in designer) and find XamlDebuggerXmlReader attribute on the top-level activity (just do textual search) and make sure that path matches the actual location of the file (you can right click the file name tab and select "Copy Full Path" to get file's full path).

Notice that specified path is relative to the output directory, so you can set it to "../../Workflow1.xaml" for example, to avoid having to fix the path every time you move the file (or forcing every developer to tweak the file for their local path).

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure because you don't provide enough information, so this is more of a "general" troubleshooting:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157687.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sonalic/archive/2006/05/10/594703.aspx
- see "Debugging and Monitoring" in http://www.devproconnections.com/article/net-framework2/introducing-net-4-0-workflow-services

EDIT: please check these http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489403.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link Yahia.  Unfortunately none of the unsupported cases match what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Breakpoint wouldn't stop on Workflow for me because I was pointing to Xaml file which is not present at right location.

Solution:  Right Click on the xaml file and Check the Tag:

```
<Sequence sad:XamlDebuggerXmlReader.FileName= "Your Xaml File Path"
```